# Writing style used in .nfo files contained with cracks for games/software

Tags: writing

I'd like to find out if this writing style has a name - and any other kind of information/history about it. It may sound a bit silly but I think allot of it was really well done and quite artistic.

I remember from being a kid, whenever you downloaded a crack for a game or piece of software the release group would write a .nfo with instructions for the crack. At the top of the file they would generally have their logo written in a style as below.

```
 _____      ___                 __                                 __
/\  _ `\  /'___`\    __        /\ \__                             /\ \__  __
\ \ \/\ \/\_\ /\ \  /\_\    ___\ \ ,_\    __   _ __    __      ___\ \ ,_\/\_\  __  __    __
 \ \ \ \ \/_/// /_  \/\ \ /' _ `\ \ \/  /'__`\/\`'__\/'__`\   /'___\ \ \/\/\ \/\ \/\ \ /'__`\
  \ \ \_\ \ // /_\ \ \ \ \/\ \/\ \ \ \_/\  __/\ \ \//\ \L\.\_/\ \__/\ \ \_\ \ \ \ \_/ /\  __/
   \ \____//\______/  \ \_\ \_\ \_\ \__\ \____\\ \_\\ \__/.\_\ \____\\ \__\\ \_\ \___/\ \____\
    \/___/ \/_____/    \/_/\/_/\/_/\/__/\/____/ \/_/ \/__/\/_/\/____/ \/__/ \/_/\/__/  \/____/
```

Sorry if this is the wrong location but I couldn't find a suitable place to post.

Comment: One program to generate this is called figlet. Maybe you find more information in its documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The broadest term is ["ASCII art"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art).

Many NFOs use a form that includes block-drawing characters which previously existed in [MS-DOS code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (though the same characters now exist in Unicode). (See also [ANSI art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_art).)

While NFOs often have hand-drawn logos and decorations, the basic shaped text that's shown in your example is often auto-generated by programs such as `banner`, `figlet`, `toilet` which come with a set of "ASCII art fonts".

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to Grawity and allo for the info. It was really interesting reading up on it.

With something to search for I was able to find this [text generator](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20) to make your own ASCII art as well.